# Unit Test Generator in Visual Studio not working

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

I've installed Unit Test Generator extension for Visual Studio 2012.

For some reason the menu item for "Generate Unit Test" sometimes appear and sometimes doesn't.

I've tried uninstalling and re installing but to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The menu item only appears if the class and function for which you try to generate a test is Public.